# How to push item of nested object into array (item not defined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object named nemesis

```
const nemesis= {
   name: 'api_G',
   badAss: true,
   inventory: [],
   health: 10,
   item: {type: "SQLinjections", damage: 100,
  },
 }
```

and I want to push from the item object the key 'type' in to the empty inventory array
using a function named: weaponize

```
  function weaponize(nemesis, item){

   let pushItem  = nemesis.item.type
   let pickItem = nemesis.inventory.push(pushItem);

   return pickItem;

  }
```

but calling the function throws an error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: when the function gets called I want "SQLinjections" to be added to the 'inventory' array .. 

so when acces the object --nemesis.inventory-- the output is "SQLinjections"..

Comment: what is `item` for in the function?

Comment: `Cannot read propery 'item' of undefined` means that the nemesis is undefined. Are you sure that you called the function with the nemesis as the first argument?

Comment: please add the call of the function as well.

Comment: @HermanL how can I make sure I am actually calling the nemesis object?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the second parameter `item` you can simply pass the `nemesis` object to the function:

```js
const nemesis= {
   name: 'api_G',
   badAss: true,
   inventory: [],
   health: 10,
   item: {type: "SQLinjections", damage: 100,
  },
 }


function weaponize(nemesis){
 let pushItem  = nemesis.item.type
 nemesis.inventory.push(pushItem);
 return nemesis;
}

console.log(weaponize(nemesis));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, and should probably be a comment instead